# Error compiling drivers for Ralink RT2870

Tags: linux, compiling, drivers, wifi

Im trying to install drivers for a rosewill RNX-N600UBE wireless card (Ralink RT2870 chipset) on Kali Linux. I downloaded the drivers form their website and unpacked/unzipped them, but now when i try to run the 'make' command i get this error.

```
/home/fox/System/2011_0427_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1156:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kuid_t’
/home/fox/System/2011_0427_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1157:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kgid_t’
make[4]: *** [/home/fox/System/2011_0427_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/fox/System/2011_0427_RT3572_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0.DPO/os/linux] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I think you might need a different version of something, maybe the compiler?

Comment: As a side-note, why would someone new to Linux fiddle with Kali? Thats a distro for security tests and attacks, packed with low level tools. Surely _not_ meant for an unexperienced linux user

Answer (score 19):

The issue is that one of the kernel headers / interfaces changed in a recent 3.x kernel. Where a UID / GID values were originally referred to as regular integers, they are now structs with a single element. Any code relying on the older definition now will fail to compile until updated to match the new kernel headers.

I'm currently experimenting with patching a similar error in virtualbox-guest-utils for my Ubuntu install; in theory locating and replacing instances of `->i_uid =` with `->i_uid.val =` or `->i_gid =` with `->i_gid.val =` on the line numbers reported in the error should fix the problem (but I can't guarantee that at this time as compilation is now failing on a different, unrelated, error for me).

Your best bet is contacting the original author of your code for an updated version of the source that works with the newer kernels.

Comment: Tested! This DOES work!

I changed `current_fsuid()` to `current_fsuid().val`

Comment: For me, I also had to change `current_fsgid()` to `current_fsgid().val`

Comment: @JonathanLeaders touché Thanks. However, the patch converting `int` to `kuid_t` also seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 12):

I found a fix to the compilation errors in another driver on this website:
http://www.arnelborja.com/compiling-rt2870-wifi-driver-in-fedora/

below is the patch content:

```
--- include/os/rt_linux.h   2013-09-12 13:27:14.000000000 +0800
+++ include/os/rt_linux.h.patched   2014-03-23 11:45:03.907628847 +0800
@@ -279,8 +279,8 @@ typedef struct file* RTMP_OS_FD;

 typedef struct _OS_FS_INFO_
 {
-   int             fsuid;
-   int             fsgid;
+   kuid_t              fsuid;
+   kgid_t              fsgid;
    mm_segment_t    fs;
 } OS_FS_INFO;
```

Comment: This is a good, working solution for the MT7601U driver, used for the Mediatek/Ralink 148F:7601 chipset, as well. (Yes, I'm just adding these keywords for SEO reasons.)

Comment: for my kernel 4.13.16-302.fc27.x86_64  on Fedora 27, this don't work anymore. Fails with compiling error.

Comment: @billyjmc: just note that, as-is, this solution does not work for kernels < 3.5, where `kuid_t` and `kgid_t` were introduced. For those, `k` must be dropped, as in `uid_t  fsuid;` and `gid_t  fsgid;`

Comment: Confirmed works on Centos 7.11 (3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64)

Answer (score 2):

`make` only reports the errors but they are in fact errors from your compiler (probably gcc):

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kuid_t’
```

Basically, your code is buggy or inappropriate for your platform but `make` functions correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me. The procedure I followed was:

1. I followed the steps for my distribution (Debian Jessie) from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x#Debian_8_.22Jessie.22).
2. I saved de driver for Linux of the manufacturer (which comes with the equipment in the CDROM), and I unzipped it to a folder.
3. In the folder, I typed `make` (as `root`), and I got an error. So, I did the modification above, and it worked.
4. I typed `make install` (as `root`), I rebooted the computer, and the wireless interface was recognized. I configured it and it worked. ;)

My system is: Debian Jessie, kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64, using gnome.