# Ralink firmware mt7601u not working on debian (ID 148f:7601)

Tags: debian, wifi

Well, fresh installed Debian Jessie (kernel 3.16.0-4-686-pae). Everything working fine, updated and upgraded. Then i got this nano wifi dongle, with rt2870 chipset. Doesn't work out of the box so i start googling.

First step was, obviously, install firmware-ralink. Everything ok. Lsmod output, grepping "rt2" here:

```
rt2800usb              21854  0 
rt2x00usb              17426  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              72379  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              41387  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              425546  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211              354137  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt              12331  1 rt2800lib
usbcore               171098  6 rt2x00usb,rt2800usb,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,xhci_hcd
```

So the modules are loaded. Reboot and nothing. Iwconfig yields this:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Then i tried to build from source, not everyday you got a CD with linux drivers on it from manufacturer and things got weirder than i can handle. Here is the make fail output:

```
david@DavidDesktop:~/Descargas/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913$ make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/david/Descargas/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/david/Descargas/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/tools'
/home/david/Descargas/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/david/Descargas/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-686-pae/build SUBDIRS=/home/david/Descargas/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-686-pae/build: No existe el fichero o el directorio.  Alto.
Makefile:394: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

I have seen and read a lot of post about troubleshoting with this chipset, but none of them works for me. Also, driver readme says this:

```
Description:
=============
This is a linux device driver for Ralink RT2870 USB ABGN WLAN Card.
```

But folder is named: "DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913"

Am i doing something like targeting the wrong chipset?

Should i blacklist some of "rt" modules? (i read about it but i never did it)

Should i modify makefile or something? (i read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125039/error-compiling-drivers-for-ralink-rt2870) question, but is beyond my knowledge where or what modify)

lsusb output:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade your kernel version .

> [Chipset is supported in Linux kernel v4.2 (and backports)](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/MediaTek_MT7601U)

You can install the `4.9` kernel version from backports: [`linux-image-686-pae`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie-backports/linux-image-686-pae)

Add backports to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Run :

```
apt-get update
apt-cache search linux-image
```

install the latest `linux-image` ...:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-base
apt-get install linux-image-xyz
apt-get install linux-headers-xyz
```

Reboot

Run :

```
apt-get install firmware-ralink firmware-misc-nonfree
modprobe mt7601u
```

Comment: linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-686-pae-unsigned : Depends: linux-base (>= 4.3~) pero 3.5 va a ser instala

Comment: `apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-base`